# What is the point of returning result of anonymous function?

Tags: go

Here is a sample code that I found online.

```golang
func FindBestKElements(nums []int, k int) []int {
    h := &IntHeap{}
    for _, val := range nums { // O(N)
        heap.Push(h, val) // O(log K)
        if h.Len() > k {
            heap.Pop(h) // O(log K)
        }
    }

    return func() []int { // O (k log k)
        result := make([]int, h.Len())
        initialLen := h.Len()
        for i := initialLen; i > 0; i-- {
            result[i-1] = heap.Pop(h).(int)
        }
        return result
    }()
}
```

The return statement of the function returns a result of running an anonymous function. I am unsure what benefits you get by doing that.

For instance, why can't we have the above method written like below?

```golang
func FindBestKElements(nums []int, k int) []int {
    h := &IntHeap{}
    for _, val := range nums { // O(N)
        heap.Push(h, val) // O(log K)
        if h.Len() > k {
            heap.Pop(h) // O(log K)
        }
    }

    result := make([]int, h.Len())
    initialLen := h.Len()
    for i := initialLen; i > 0; i-- {
        result[i-1] = heap.Pop(h).(int)
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: There is no benefit in returning the result of a function as you showed in the first snippet. Your second snippet is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be redundant in the given example. However in some cases it can be
useful. Take this example:

```
package main

func main() {
   a := []int{10, 20, 30, 40}
   var b bool
   for _, n := range a {
      if n == 20 { b = true }
   }
   if b {
      println("pass")
   } else {
      println("fail")
   }
}
```

Instead of using the state variable `b`, you could use another function:

```
package main

func main() {
   a := []int{10, 20, 30, 40}
   if func() bool {
      for _, n := range a {
         if n == 20 { return true }
      }
      return false
   }() {
      println("pass")
   } else {
      println("fail")
   }
}
```